# What is the value of the given periodic signal at any time, how to solve it in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, periodic

Firstly hello all, I need help about periodic signals. I have a question as below.

> $x(t)$ is a **periodic signal** and $0.1t^3[u(t) - u(t - 7)]$
> describes its **one period**.
>
> What is the value of $x(t)$ at time $t = 317$?
>
> **Hint:** Determine one period of the signal and find its values.

How can we solve this in MATLAB ? I tried with the code below, but answer was not correct

```
x(t) = 0.1 * t^3 * (heaviside(t) - heaviside(t - 7));
ezplot(x);
x(317)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming continuous-time for the probem, for all periodic signals with a period of $T$ , for any integer $m$ , we have :

$$  x( t + mT) = x(t) \tag{1}$$

So, for example with  $T=7$ , and $m=2$ , you can see that $x(15) = x(2\cdot 7 + 1) = x(1)$. The operator that is used to find base argument for a given $t$ value is the **modulus** :

$$ x(t) = x( \text{mod}(t,T) ) \tag{2}$$

where $\text{mod}(t,T)$ is the modulus of $t$ wrt $T$.

For your example, your period is $T=7$, and you can see that $x(315) = x( \text{mod}(315,7) ) = x(2)$.

Hence the value of $x(t)$ for $t=2$ is $0.1 \cdot 2^3 = 0.8$.

I don't know if there's anything to solve with MATLAB here though?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)